# Discord bot doesn't work while online, bot running

Tags: discord, discord.py

I was starting to code a discord bot in Python. But now I struggle with something pretty big:
The bot doesn't send the messages

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
general_channel = client.get_channel(798136768120881165)
join_channel = client.get_channel(798194832442130444)

@client.event
async def on_member_join(ctx, member):
    await ctx.join_channel.send(f"Welcome to my server! <@userid>")

@client.event
async def on_message(context):
    if message.content == "What is this?":
        
        WhatEmbed = discord.Embed(title="This is a TestBot", description="It's my first bot ever made!", color=0x00ff00)

    await context.message.channel.send(embed=WhatEmbed)

@client.command(aliases=['help'])
async def help(message):

    helpEmbed = discord.Embed(title="Help", description=None, colour=discord.Colour.gray())

    await message.channel.send(helpEmbed=helpEmbed)
```

The bot is running and it is online

Comment: You forget fomule: await client.process_commands(message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You messed up your code a bit.

- `on_message` doesn't take the `Context` manager, it takes `message`
- The `help` command doesn't take `message` as the argument, it takes `Context`
- `on_member_join` only takes a single argument, `member`

You should also add `client.process_commands` at the end of the `on_message` event and enable some intents.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    print(f"Bot is online")


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    join_channel = client.get_channel(798194832442130444)
    await join_channel.send(f"Welcome to my server! <@userid>") # if you want to mention the member use `member.mention`


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "What is this?":
        WhatEmbed = discord.Embed(title="This is a TestBot", description="It's my first bot ever made!", color=0x00ff00)
        await message.channel.send(embed=WhatEmbed)

    await client.process_commands(message)


@client.command(aliases=['help'])
async def help(ctx):
    helpEmbed = discord.Embed(title="Help", description=None, colour=discord.Colour.gray())
    await ctx.send(helpEmbed=helpEmbed)
```

I enabled `intents.members` cause you have the `on_member_join` event, remember to also enable them in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

#### Reference:

- [`on_member_join`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member#discord.on_member_join)
- [`on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message)
- [`on_ready`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_ready#discord.on_ready)

Comment: Thanks for answering! This was the solution

Comment: No worries, remember to accept the answer if it helped

Comment: If I want to send a message in a specific channel with ```general_channel = client.get_channel(channelid) I call client, but I never defined client with the discord.Client, do I still have to define this?

Comment: You defined client, but it's an instance of `commands.Bot` - it has all the functionality of `discord.Client` + a full command system, if you check out the docs, `commands.Bot` also has a method [`get_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=get_channel#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_channel)

Comment: I want to add a command "!online" which says if the bot is online/updating

Comment: If the bot is updating it will be offline and none of the commands will work, pretty useless command if you ask me